# Error when updating Shipment with REST PUT

Tags: acumatica

Getting the following in response when doing Rest PUT on an existing Shipment.
System.InvalidCastException: [A]PX.Objects.IN.INUnitExt cannot be cast to [B]PX.Objects.IN.INUnitExt. Type A originates from 'RuntimeCode_40DD5542ECC5527, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location... [A] and [B] refer to two files in the Customization folder. Both these files look almost identical.

Any clues or guides on how to identify the issue would be appreciated. I'll suppl with more detail later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regularly happens after publishing a customization. Simply restart the site by using iisreset if you have access or use the Restart button that is available in the Apply Updates page.

Comment: @Des can you mark the answer as correct/accepted? Thanks!